# Devise security extension config.password_regex being ingored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

For some reason `devise.rb` configuration file seems to be ignoring by regex command in the config, any ideas on why it would be doing this?

`devise.rb`

```
# Need 1 char of A-Z, a-z and 0-9 and a special character
  config.password_regex = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])/
```

I'm using the devise security extension gem: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: you've restarted your rails server right? (i'm looking into your question right now, but devise config only reloads after the server has been restarted, so i wanted to get possibility out of the way)

Comment: Yeah I have, also I realised I was using :validatable, instead of :secure_validatable in the user model, so that's most likely the issue but now when I swap the two around it throws the error: ArgumentError: Unknown validator: 'EmailValidator' ..I have to go on a hunt to find out what's causing this subsequent issue.

Comment: Password still being ignored after using :secure_validatable, the issue in my previous comment was due to the dependent gems for that module not being installed

Comment: did you run `devise :secure_validatable` in the terminal?

Comment: @RushRed please have a look at my answer and feel free to accept it if it helps :)

Comment: Can you please tell me if my answer helped you RushRed?

Answer (score 2):

This `config.password_regex` option is provided by [the devise_security_extension gem](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension), which is no more supported, but a fork has been created and replaces that gem which is [the devise-security gem](https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security).

In this fork they decided to [replace `password_regex` by `password_complexity`](https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security/commit/e2f7f8fcacf447a92bb31ac8883845fc575b2c1f) which defines it in a simpler manner as you just pass a Hash with the kind of accepted characters and its amount :

```
config.password_complexity = { digit: 1, lower: 1, symbol: 1, upper: 1 }
```

This means the password must contain at least 1 digit, one lower case character, one uppercase character and one symbol character.
This is compliant with the Regex you gave as an example.